# adjustPrecision not working in amcharts

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, amcharts, donut-chart

I have a js file which uses amchart,
**I'm having a problem of total percentage in Donut chart not having the value as 100%.**
I followed their doc [AmPieChart#adjustPrecision](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#adjustPrecision)
But still even after setting 
`charti.adjustPrecision= true;` the total percentage is not tallied to 100%

Below is my piece of code.

```
chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();


    chart.colors = ["#7498BF",  "#76B900"];
    if(combineRow){
        chart.groupPercent = 5;
    }
    chart.startDuration = 0;

    chart.dataProvider = dataJson;
    chart.titleField = "category";
    chart.descriptionField = "description";
    chart.valueField = "amount";
    chart.radius = "30%";
    chart.outlineThickness = 2;
    chart.sequencedAnimation = false;
    chart.startEffect = "bounce";
    chart.startRadius="30";
    chart.colorField = "color";
    chart.startDuration = 0;
    chart.innerRadius = "30%";
    chart.labelsEnabled = false;
    chart.labelRadius = "-1";
    chart.hideLabelsPercent="3";
    chart.balloonText="[[description]]: [[percents]]% ($[[value]])";

    chart.adjustPrecision= true;


    legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.align = "center";
    legend.markerType = "square";
    legend.markerLabelGap = 5;
    legend.markerSize = 12;
    legend.marginTop = 0;
    legend.marginBottom = 0;
    legend.spacing = 20;
    legend.position = "right";
    legend.fontSize = 10;

    legend.valueText = "[[percents]]%";
    legend.valueWidth = 83;

    chart.addLegend(legend);
    chart.addListener("clickSlice", callBackFunction);




chart.write(containerId);
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Can we have a working demo ? Either JSFiddle or JSbin like something ?

Comment: @theRoot can you at least provide sample data that reproduces the issue? I can't reproduce it with dummy data [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gghLtgt9/)

Comment: thanks guys for your replies, when I tried to reproduce in their Live editor, I got correct rounding.  The problem was ,I was using 2.8.1 but in 3.14.1 adjustPrecision was introduced.